# Deploying MonoGame without OpenAL or Installer

Tags: monogame, deployment

I just shipped my first working MonoGame in-development game to one of my friends. He got some OpenAL DLL crashes, until he installed OpenAL.

Is there a way to include the OpenAL dependencies somehow with my game? I noticed Visual Studio already copies MonoGame, OpenTK, Tao.SDL, etc. to the `bin` directory.

**Edit:** XNA/MonoGame/VisualStudio already creates all the required DLLs, content, etc. in `bin`; it's only OpenAL that doesn't appear (there's no DLL). What's the best way to handle this *without creating an installer?*

Comment: Why don't you just include the OpenAL install in your install process?

Comment: Because I don't *have* an install process :)

Comment: "*Because I don't have an install process*" You're already depending on OpenTK, Tao.SDL, and so forth, so that's a problem you're going to have to *fix* sooner or later.

Comment: @NicolBolas Visual Studio already puts forward all the DLLs when I build. I failed to see why I would *need* an installation process. OpenAL is a bit different, since it doesn't have an associated .NET DLL.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you could attempt to put the openal32.dll and wrap_oal.dll files along with the rest of your bins.  It should technically work, but again I have not tested this.

Comment: @ashes999: people not using Visual Studio will want an installer.  There's a reason all shipping games use them.  There are a ton of free and easy to use installer builders, it takes like 15 minutes to make one.  Just do it.

Comment: I actually tried @Jon's suggestion with my game recently and still had users report issues. I think the silent installer is the only way to go.

Comment: @craftworkgames what kind of issues did you see?

Comment: @ashes999 Added it as an answer.

Comment: The issue I saw was that the users still had to install OpenAL with the installer even when the DLL's where in the same directory as the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you could attempt to put the openal32.dll and wrap_oal.dll files along with the rest of your bins. It should technically work, but again I have not tested this.

Comment: OpenAL shouldn't be installed like this where possible - it's bad practice and has side-effects as noted by a user in the original question comments.

Comment: I agree.  I was requested to put this as an answer.

Comment: I disagree. This worked for me and is the simplest solution. +1

Answer (score 8):

Just run the OpenAL installer inside of your install process.

You should be deploying your game with some sort of installer anyway to include libraries you might have and do other legwork, so just include another step in your build process to install OpenAL with the silent flag. For OpenAL this is:

> /S or /s or -S or -s
>   The installation runs in silent mode. Nothing will be displayed.

[Reference](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/OpenAL%20Wiki/Installer%20Options%20On%20Windows.aspx)

This should be all you need to ensure every user has OpenAL installed before they try and run your game.

Comment: I've never shipped any XNA games, so I never ran into this before -- I usually just zip up binaries. What's the "usual" developer's choice for Windows/XNA installation?

Comment: I've updated my question. I would like to avoid needing an installer (OpenAL is the only reason I need it today, which I don't even use in Windows apps). If there's no better answer, a winnar is you.

Comment: The alternative is including OpenAL in the EXE itself and unpacking itself upon the system if it's not installed. I can include an example below if you need implementation details.

Comment: @ashes999 Or copying all the OpenAL stuff to the directory if OpenAL requires no additional registry keys etc.

Comment: what install software/kit do you recommend? I tried ClickOnce and NSIS without success.